# pandas subplot title size

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have recently figured out that I can use plot function directly from pandas without using Seaborn for quick visualisations.

I used the following code to generate a series of graphs from the data frame that contains years as the first column and the price for different product in the rest of the columns.

```
df_annual_price.plot.line(x='Date',
                          subplots=True, 
                          layout=(5,5),
                          figsize=(60,60),
                          fontsize=20,
                          sharex=False,
                          title = list_of_products
                         )
```

It neatly graphs the lineplot for all the columns. However, one thing I can't figure out is how to control the fontsize of the title for each plot. I have tried to look it up in other threads but couldn't find an answer.

Is there a simple and elegant answer to this?

Comment: Not sure if it is of any help but one way is to assign the title a posteriori:
plt.title('your title', fontsize=15')
If you have subplots use the ax.set_title instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas's `plot()` with `subplots=True` option returns a list (or list of lists) of axes.

We could enumerate each axis and call its `set_title()` with title and font size.
This is how you change the title font size of each subplot.

We could pick any one of the axes and call its `get_figure()` to obtain the `Figure` object of the overall plot. Then we could call `Figure`'s `suptitle()` with title and font size.  This is how you change the title font size of the overall figure.

The example below creates a 2 x 2 subplots and illustrates functions which may be useful for people who are new to MatplotLib and Pandas's `plot()` function.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


labels = ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4']
x = 'x'
columns = [x] + labels

matrix = np.random.rand(10, 5)
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=columns)
df = df.sort_values(by=x)

axes = df.plot(
    x=x,
    y=labels,
    subplots=True,
    layout=(2,2),
    kind='hist',
    figsize=(8,8)
)

for i, row in enumerate(axes):
    for j, ax in enumerate(row):
        ax.set_title(f'Subplot {i, j}', fontsize=12)
        ax.set_xlabel('Width')
        ax.set_ylabel('Percentage')

fig = axes[0, 0].get_figure()
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.9, wspace=0.3, hspace=0.3)
_ = fig.suptitle(f'Distribution of Widths', fontsize=16)  # suppress printing of title
```

[image]

Pandas's `plot()` accepts **`**kwargs`** parameters which could be passed to its underlying `matplotlib.pyplot.plot()`. See https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html for various parameters.

Comment: Thanks for that. It really helped and I have arranged the data how I wanted it. I was hoping for a one liner inside of the plot function itself but that still works well.